# Obtain vectors of the form : [1,1,1,1]

Tags: algorithm, hash, binary, sum

I have the following problem, given a set n of vectors of the same dimension m, these vectors have the form [0,1,0,1,1,1,1]. I want to obtain all combinations of vectors such that adding the positions m_i obtains vectors of the form: [1,1,1,1,1,1]. I want to know if anyone knows how to do this without brute force?

Thank you

Comment: I am going to implement this algorithm in python but it is indifferent, I can write it.

Comment: I would expect `m` and `n` to be reasonably small, otherwise it would be impossible to enumerate all combinations for some sets of vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the 'Exact Cover Problem,' and is NP-compete.

There's a good (readable) paper by Knuth on a technique called 'Dancing Links' that can be used to solve this problem.

[https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Ejchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover